# controlling a form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I want to ask. what if I have a form in a (View folder) **gatepass.php** and this page was called by (view)main_frame page navigator/menu bar unto its page. this main_frame page was called by the controller **home.php**

how can I call the form into the **gatepassController.php**?
can I do that? I want gatepassController.php to control the form in gatepass.php so that the home.php won't be crowded by other pages.

I also have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\views\gatepass.php on line 109

I don't know where to call that form. It is very important to me. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is occur because you forgot to load the form helper. Add below code in `application/config/autoload.php` or

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','text','form');
```

OR

Add the following line into your controller before loading the view:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Read [Document](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: how can I add application/config/autoload.php? and where do I add this?

Comment: you sure? this what I get..

Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\nici_cs\application\config\autoload.php on line 115

Comment: yes. thank you very much!! but how can I call the form in gatepasscontroller.php? let's say that the name of the form is gatepassform. I'm really sorry for causing you trouble.